# close() after system() weird behavior

Tags: c, sockets, system

I'm calling `system("bash ../tools/bashScript \"This is an argument!\" &")`, then I'm calling `close(socketFD)` directly after `system` returns, of course I've read that `system`'s argument appended with a `&` will `fork` the `command`, so `system` returns immediately and I've checked that!

Now the problem is that I don't want the socket to stay connected while the `command` is being executed, but the weirdest thing is that the work flow of the program continues and `close` is somewhat seen and overlooked and once the `command` finishes the `close` takes effect!

I tried to call `close` twice after each others to make sure to delete every copy of the `socketFD` if created, still the same problem, I honestly don't know why `close` is being called but doesn't take effect until the `command` (the bash script) finishes!

Please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused about what you're doing, but `system` is effectively a thin wrapper over `fork`.  This means that both processes have copies* of the socket descriptor, and only one "copy" is closed.  The other persists until the forked process in which the `system` command is executing terminates as well.

Why not just close the socket before you call `system`?

You could also try using `shutdown` on the `dup`'d descriptors, e.g.:

```
shutdown(s,SHUT_RDWR);
```

**Tthe rules around what happens to file and socket descriptors through `fork` calls is a little more subtle than "copying", but this is sufficient to explain why it's not working for you.*

Comment: I can't cause I have to send a message after, `system` is called in a different function that returns then `close` is being called after `write`ing a message to a socket, I also tried to call `close` twice and still the same problem.

Comment: That's just not how that works.  Are you trying to make the socket hang up on the client?

Comment: Yeah I wanna close the connection, I'm trying what you've said right now.

Comment: OK, I just updated my answer with some code that will work from the parent process (i.e., after `system` is called).